# Warum steht das Verb "wird" an dritter Stelle?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammatical-case

> Erst Anfang des 16. Jahrhunderts beginnt das kanonische Zinsverbot zu **bröckeln, die** Verzinsung von Darlehen in einzelnen deutschen Ländern und Städten **wird** per Gesetz erlaubt

1. Warum stehet das Verb "wird"  an dritter Stelle und nicht nach "Darlehen"
2. Was ist die Relation zwischen dem ersten und zweiten Satz um komma zu schreiben? Sie sind grammatisch gespaltet aber der zweite Satz verstärkt die Bedeutung des ersten Satz ?

Comment: Nach welcher Zählweise ist "wird" an dritter Stelle? Es ist das zweite finite Verb im Satzgefüge und das zweite Satzglied in seinem Hauptsatz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es handelt sich um verkettete Hauptsätze. *Man könnte auch einen Punkt schreiben, im Deutschen wird jedoch eher das Komma gesetzt, um gedanklich zusammenhängende Hauptsätze zu kennzeichnen.* Der Punkt schließt einen Gedankengang ab. Der Absatz schließt im Deutschen hingegen eine Argumentation ab.

Der kursiv gesetzte Satz oben verdeutlicht das Prinzip. Nach *schreiben* könnte auch ein Punkt stehen, er entspräche allerdings nicht dem üblichen Stil.

Das ist ein wesentlicher Stilunterschied z.B. zum Englischen, im dem ein solches Komma ein Stilfehler wäre. Im Deutschen sind hingegen Anreihungen von kurzen Hauptsätzen mit Punkt verpönt, weil sie dann wie ungeordnete Gedanken wirken.

---

Es gibt zwei Möglichkeiten, den zweiten Hauptsatz zu bilden:

> Die Verzinsung von Darlehen in einzelnen deutschen Ländern und Städten wird per Gesetz erlaubt.

In diesem Satz ist *in einzelnen deutschen Ländern* eine Ergänzung des Subjekts *Die Verzinsung*, übrigens genau wie die Ergänzung *von Darlehen* auch. Das Hilfsverb *wird* ist der zweite Satzteil.

> Die Verzinsung von Darlehen wird in einzelnen deutschen Ländern und Städten per Gesetz erlaubt.

In diesem Satz ist *in einzelnen deutschen Ländern* ist *in einzelnen deutschen Ländern* hingegen eine adverbiale Bestimmung des Prädikats.

Comment: gibt es Bücher zu Satzzeichensetzung ?

Comment: Auf welchem Niveau? Die wesentlichen Regeln stehen in jeder guten Grammatik, ein angehender Schreiber würde sich vor allem an dem orientieren, was seine Kollegen schreiben.

Comment: gibt es auf C2 Niveau ?

Comment: @user26646: es gibt [nur wenige Regeln](http://canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Interpunktion/index.html?MenuId=OfficialSpelling14&lang=en), die in **allen** guten Lehrbüchern stehen sollten.

Comment: Also § 67 Fall E1.

Comment: In German, a comma splice is not frowned upon, it is used quite often. <g>